# can I mount the sink 50 cm away from the wall drain hole

Tags: drain, pipe, kitchen-sink

let s say I have 250 cm available for my kitchen and the wall drain hole is at 125 cm from the wall, half way. Can i mount the sink away from the wall drain hole say at 70 cm from the wall and have a drain pipe going from the location of the sink to the wall connection? or is it too far for correct draining of my sink?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Is the existing drain hole in the wall or floor?

Comment: I don't understand from your question, why you would have a problem. Pipes are designed for exactly this!? Maybe a diagram would help to clarify what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the Sink further out from a wall would be easy and not present any problems for the drain. Moving to the side may require an additional elbow. If the drain is properly sized and vented it should work in both cases. Maintaining a slope on the longer horizontal line will improve performance and reduce the possibility of solids collecting and causing problems.